# OpenWrt Luci - importing an external javascript file

Tags: openwrt, luci

I am attempting to extract a variable from my Luci module plugin into its own file so I can reuse it.

graph_objects.js:

```
'use strict';
'require baseclass';
'require uci';

const graph_objects = {...};

return graph_objects;
```

gauges.js (importing graph_objects here):

```
var graph_objects = L.resource('statistics/rrdtool/definitions/graph_objects.js');
```

My error in Luci:

```
TypeError
"statistics.rrdtool.definitions.graph_objects" factory yields invalid constructor
```

Other things I have tried:

```
export const myVariable = 'some value';
```

```
import { myVariable } from './config.js';
```

and

```
module.exports.myVariable = 'some value';
```

```
const { myVariable } = require('./config.js');
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who takes the time to help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `L.resource()` only lets you load js files which are subclass of Luci.js.

@kbessemer maybe you can store the variable in session storage like [this](https://openwrt.github.io/luci/jsapi/LuCI.session.html#setLocalData) and use it wherever you want.

You will have to write a onload function that will load the value in session storage, refer [this](https://github.com/openwrt/luci/blob/e557e1782931246dc345e29cbd9c56e49f5c612d/applications/luci-app-babeld/htdocs/luci-static/resources/view/babeld/babeld-view.js#L61)

Or maybe I am misunderstanding your requirement, in that case please add some more code so it will be better to understand.